# Logistic Regression using Python statsmodel

Tags: python, logistic-regression, data-analysis, statsmodels, dummy-variable

I am new to the Analytics field and I have few doubts.
I hope I can get my answers here.

I am in the middle of implementing Logistic regression using python.
If we need to apply the logistic on the categorical variables, I have implemented get_dummies for that. Suppose the column name is house type (Beach, Mountain and Plain).
What we do here is create three dummy variables in this case and drop one of them, as we can infer the Plain using the other 2 dummy variables.

But when I implement RFE on the data. Do I need to include all the 3 variables?
(I saw this in some blog where dummy was not dropped and got confused)

Also, I need to add an intercept column also, as I was using statsmodel (which does not add intercept on it's own). So, in that case if there are multiple categorical variables (and we have dropped a dummy for each) there won't be any issue right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end up seeing multicolinearity as the third dummy column is always the opposite of the sum of the first two (1 if they sum to 0, and 0 if they sum to 1).

This should be removed prior to feature selection, such as RFE.

If you don't, statsmodel is going to throw an warning in the summary and if you check the VIF of the features post fitting, you'll see unacceptable scores that are suggesting colinear features.

In any case once this is done, it is feasible that one of your dummy columns could actually be a constant, such as if you had no beach houses in your data set.  The default behavior of statsmodel ignore the add_constant statement when a constant exists.  To get around this you may consider  the has_constant parameter, passing 'add' to indicate you'd like to get an intercept even if there is already a constant column.

`X = sm.add_constant(X, has_constant='add'`)

Comment: Am sorry, I didn't get your part (adding constant). Also, could you please help me understand why we add intercept?

Comment: Don't worry too much about the code, just make sure you add a constant to your data prior to fitting if you want an intercept. If one of your columns is already constant (has all of the same values) the has_constant helps by adding an intercept anyway.  You can think of the intercept as what the house is worth just for existing, without considering any other variable.  The other features such as being on the beach, having a garage, etc will add or subtract from that value to give you the estimated value, which can then be used to classify the house in your logistic reg.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one more small doubt, If we convert 2-3 categorical vars to dummy variables, we drop one for each column? And for all the columns there would be just one constant right?  Also, are get_dummies and label encoding the same ?

Comment: I would suggest looking up correlation matrix before you move on, to better understand why or when to drop features.  That should clear up most of your questions.

Comment: For feature selection, I did RFE only. And after that also there were 2 different categorical vars, for which dummy was created. For those dummy variables one constant is enough right ?

Comment: Perhaps accept this answer if it addressed the original problem, then ask a new question.